# Tuple item replacement in Python

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
a = [
    ((5,7),15,(5,3)),
    ((2,1),8,(4,3)),
    ((4,7),9,(4,2))
]
```

and a tuple:

```
b = ((5,7),9,(4,2))
```

and I want to complete the action in quotes:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][0] == b[0]:
        if a[i][1] > b[1]:
            "replace a[i][1] with b[1]"
```

but this assignment is not supported

Comment: `tuple`s are immutable, you can't modify them.

Comment: tuples in python are immutable, that means you can't change their value after definition, if you want mutable tuple, use a list.

Comment: Ok, thanks I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

`a[i][1]` and `b[1]` are `Tuples`.
consider that you can not do such things to Tuple items.
because ***Tuple item is not changeable***.
you can change all of your collections to list and run your code:

```
a = [[[5, 7],15,[5, 3]], [[2, 1], 8, [4, 3]], [[4, 7], 9, [4, 2]]]

b = [[5,7],9,[4,2]]  

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][0] == b[0]:
        if a[i][1] > b[1]:
            a[i][1] = b[1]
            print(a)
```